Switching x-axis and z-axis To appear instead of each other
I want to have a horizontal cone $z=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$. I've written a code for vertical cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ like below. If I switch the x-axis and z-axis then I would have a horizontal cone just with same code. Could anyone help me, please?
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=1\textwidth, height=1\textwidth,
            xmin=-4, xmax=4,
            ymin=-4, ymax=4,
            zmin=-4, zmax=4,
            axis equal,
            axis lines=center,
            xtick={-5,...,5},
            ytick={-5,...,5},
            ztick={-3,...,3}]
            \addplot3[surf, shader=flat, draw=gray, fill=gray, ultra thin, opacity=0.5, fill opacity=0.5, data cs=polar, domain=0:360, y domain=0:2, restrict z to domain=0:4,] (x,y,y);
            \addplot3[surf, shader=flat, draw=gray, fill=gray, ultra thin, opacity=0.5, fill opacity=0.5, data cs=polar, domain=0:360, y domain=0:2, restrict z to domain=-4:0,] (x,y,-y);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Do you just want a horizontal cone or do you really want your x-axis to point upwards(very unusual and not easy).

A horizontal cone with this code. Since z-axis is vertical so cone would be vertical. Thus if z axis be horizontal then the cone would be horizontal too.

your question is not so clear! Can you provide a sketchy hand-drawing picture of what you want to get?

Since I dont have enough reputation to comment, here is a post based on this answer
\documentclass[tikz, border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
zmin=-4, zmax=4,
axis equal,
axis lines=center,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-5,...,5},
ztick={-3,...,3},
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
gray, ultra thin, opacity=0.5,
domain=-90:90, y domain=0:2,
] (y,{y*sin(x)},{y*cos(x)});
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
gray, ultra thin, opacity=0.5,
domain=90:270, y domain=-2:0,
] (y,{y*sin(x)},{y*cos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you. This works properly.

data cs=polar is polar in x-y plane. Here is an alternative:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-4, xmax=4,
ymin=-4, ymax=4,
zmin=-4, zmax=4,
axis equal,
axis lines=center,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-5,...,5},
ztick={-3,...,3},
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
gray, ultra thin, opacity=0.5,
domain=0:360, y domain=-2:2,
] (y,{y*sin(x)},{y*cos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you, Is it possible to manipulate this code so that we have also a cone just for positive z? That is upper part of horizontal cone?

Your code is for y^2+z^2=x^2. I also need for z=sqrt(x^2-y^2) and z=-sqrt(x^2-y^2)
